# Missing right parenthesis error in Oracle but not in H2

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been struggling with this query for a while. This runs fine with H2 but I don't know why it is throwing this error in Oracle:

```
18:09:02,1 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In all likelihood, the expression `efd.gfcid IN (:gfcids)` does *not* do what you expect.

Comment: Two things: 1. your strings are enclosed by two single quotes, correct syntax is just one single quote,  2. this is no pure SQL since you are using bind variables. Try to replace the bind variables with literal data and test your statement manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I formatted your code I noticed that you had double single quotes around the string `PRESHIP_FIN_CONVERSION_TENOR`.
Change this:

```
WHERE efd.ATTRIBUTE_NAME = ''PRESHIP_FIN_CONVERSION_TENOR''
```

To this:

```
WHERE efd.ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'PRESHIP_FIN_CONVERSION_TENOR'
```

In both subqueries.

Answer (score 3):

> WHERE efd.ATTRIBUTE_NAME = ''PRESHIP_FIN_CONVERSION_TENOR''

Shouldn't the value be enclosed within **single quotation marks**? Do that at both places in the query.

In Oracle, you use single quotes for strings.

Comment: And double quotes for columns!

Comment: And not only "in Oracle" - but "in SQL" (the query language) in general.

Comment: @jarlh, aliases precisely. Columns only when it is a keyword.